# No multiple *.onion domain possible

Tags: debian, networking, apache-virtualhost, tor

I have some problems with adding a second *.onion address. I added following:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service2/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8081
```

in the `torrc-file`, and the first *.onion domain is reachable, but the second one is not. What can I do?

My settings are: apache2-Server on a Debian Buster with installed keyhelp. I've added the *.onion domain an existing customer (with clearnet domain too) and both are reachable. So I added a new customer, added the additional two lines in `torrc`, got the new *.onion domain, which I added at the new customer, after tor restart in the `hidden_service2` dir, but this is not reachable with the Tor browser.

Here is the log:

```
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8197]: Interrupt: exiting cleanly.
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de systemd[1]: Stopping Anonymizing overlay network for TCP...
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de systemd[1]: tor@default.service: Succeeded.
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de systemd[1]: Stopped Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de systemd[1]: Starting Anonymizing overlay network for TCP...
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de tor[8704]: Dec 09 16:43:35.337 [notice] Tor 0.4.1.6 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1d
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de tor[8704]: Dec 09 16:43:35.338 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https:/
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de tor[8704]: Dec 09 16:43:35.339 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de tor[8704]: Dec 09 16:43:35.339 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de tor[8704]: Configuration was valid
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de tor[8706]: Dec 09 16:43:35.474 [notice] Tor 0.4.1.6 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1d
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de tor[8706]: Dec 09 16:43:35.475 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https:/
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de tor[8706]: Dec 09 16:43:35.475 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de tor[8706]: Dec 09 16:43:35.475 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de tor[8706]: Dec 09 16:43:35.480 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de tor[8706]: Dec 09 16:43:35.481 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: We compiled with OpenSSL 1010103f: OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019 and we are running with OpenSSL 10101
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Tor 0.4.1.6 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1d, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma 5.2.4,
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Starting with guard context "default"
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de systemd[1]: Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
Dez 09 16:43:35 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Signaled readiness to systemd
Dez 09 16:43:36 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
Dez 09 16:43:36 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Opening Socks listener on /run/tor/socks
Dez 09 16:43:36 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Opened Socks listener on /run/tor/socks
Dez 09 16:43:36 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Opening Control listener on /run/tor/control
Dez 09 16:43:36 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Opened Control listener on /run/tor/control
Dez 09 16:43:36 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
Dez 09 16:43:36 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay
Dez 09 16:43:36 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done
Dez 09 16:43:36 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Bootstrapped 75% (enough_dirinfo): Loaded enough directory info to build circuits
Dez 09 16:43:36 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Bootstrapped 90% (ap_handshake_done): Handshake finished with a relay to build circuits
Dez 09 16:43:36 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Bootstrapped 95% (circuit_create): Establishing a Tor circuit
Dez 09 16:43:37 XXXXXXX.XXXXX.de Tor[8706]: Bootstrapped 100% (done): Done
```

Comment: Can you restart the tor service, and then share the systemd log for tor? You can edit out any confidential information before post but it's good to see what they tor daemon is doing when it starts.

Comment: I´ve added the log

Answer (score 0):

I changed the ports as follows:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service2/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

Now I can manage the generated onion domain in keyhelp and add it to a user. I guess here keyhelp takes over the allocation of the domains.